# Chrome doesn't vertically align text in table cell

Tags: css, google-chrome, vertical-alignment

Active site can be seen here: http://twoacr.es/

When a `.project-panel` is hovered, a div fades in over with text in it. I have it set as a `table` and the content within as `table-cell`, it works great in Firefox but Chrome seems to ignore the height and puts the type all at the top. I've tried it a number of different ways but Chrome always seems to act up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on your browser support requirements, there are a number of alternative ways to vertical center without relying on tables.

You can use absolute positioning combined with a transform.
Or you can use flexbox.

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.absolute {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box flexbox">
   <h3>Center</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box absolute">
   <h3>Center</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please look at the link I added for example.

I think it works in your example because you're explicitly setting a height, but in my example linked, heights are variable based on the image the overlay is appearing on, and there are varying amounts of text, so the translate doesn't work either.

Comment: As long as the container is big enough to contain the text, it will work. The declared height is not necessary. It was provided simply for presentational purposes. I was able to get it to work on your example site by editing the css in the dev panel. Change display: table to display: block on '.project-overlay' and add the following lines to the first child: `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`

Comment: Perfect, seems to work! I think I was just getting stuck on the table/table-cell method, couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Thanks so much.